# Create "Fake" audio device in C#?

Tags: c#, audio, stream, capture

I was wondering if it would be possible to create a 'fake' audio device. I've got a program which streams to Twitch and it captures all of the audio on the selected audio device. I want to create an audio device via my own program for this streaming software to listen to. That way it will only be able to stream the sound which I send to the virtual device.

How should I approach this? I'm assuming it's possible because there are fake webcam programs etc which can produce a similar effect but with video.

Comment: It's possible somehow... since Virtual Audio Cable does it. It's likely not possible in pure C# though, you'll need some C/C++ to achieve it (or C++/CLI). As to HOW to do it, I've wondered this for a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that is not possible. To create a "Fake audio device" (as you call it), you have to write an audio driver. Download the WinDDK to get a few examples on how to do that. Anyway, you won't find any example coded in C# because it is not possible to write drivers with C#.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look further into it and see if it's worth attempting.

Comment: I know I'm digging up an old thread, but that's statement is not entirely true. As far as I know since the beginning of .NET you could create wrappers for C++ libraries, so you can access methods and classes from the C# world. You could take the Microsoft samples in the DDK, create accessor methods and objects, and C# them away. With today's C# 4.6, native compiled binaries are pretty fast and can possibly be used for such timing intensive tasks.

Comment: don't know whether there is a "hack" for creating drivers with the native compiler, but i guess it would be impossible or extremely tricky.